# Rails maintaining selected value for states using a helper in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm going through and cleaning up some forms and realized that when a user clicks to edit a training the state reverts back to Alaska instead of whatever state it was currently on. Right now the code looks like this in the helper:

```
module Admin::StatesHelper
 STATES = [
  ['Alaska', 'AK'],
  ['Alabama', 'AL'],
  ['Arkansas', 'AR'],
  ['American Samoa', 'AS'],
  ['Arizona', 'AZ'],
  ['California', 'CA'],
  ['Colorado', 'CO'],
  ['Connecticut', 'CT'],
  ['District of Columbia', 'DC']
  ].freeze

def options_for_us_state(selected = nil, abbrev_only: true)
  values = abbrev_only ? STATES.map { |s| s[1] } : STATES
  options_for_select(values, selected)
end
end
```

Then in the form we have:

```
<%= f.tb_select :state, options_for_us_state(params[:state]), prompt: 'Select State'%>
```

I could create states as it's separate model then use options_from_collection_for_select but shouldn't my method be working or did I put in something that's not catching the selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the stupid form. Used the following:

```
<%= f.tb_select :state, options_for_us_state(@location.state), prompt: 'Select State'%>
```